# Fill NaN values of selected dataframe columns using For loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, nan, fillna

I have a dataframe of patients Vital signs (HR, O2Sat, Temp, SBP, DBP, Resp) with NaN values. I filled NaN in individual patient based on Patient ID (P_ID) column using the code:

```
m['HR'] = m['HR'].fillna(m.groupby('P_ID')['HR'].transform('mean'))
m['O2Sat'] = m['O2Sat'].fillna(m.groupby('P_ID')['O2Sat'].transform('mean'))
m['Temp'] = m['Temp'].fillna(m.groupby('P_ID')['Temp'].transform('mean'))
m['SBP'] = m['SBP'].fillna(m.groupby('P_ID')['SBP'].transform('mean'))
m['DBP'] = m['DBP'].fillna(m.groupby('P_ID')['DBP'].transform('mean'))
m['Resp'] = m['Resp'].fillna(m.groupby('P_ID')['Resp'].transform('mean'))
```

It worked perfectly. However it is a lot of code. Is there anyway I use **for loop** to fill NaN values in only the vital columns? As there are some more columns without NaN values. Thanks.

Comment: What are the "vital columns"? Are all of the columns vital?

Comment: I mean vital sign columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a loop

```
for i in ['HR','O2Sat','Temp','SBP','DBP','Resp']:
    m[i] = m[i].fillna(m.groupby('P_ID')[i].transform('mean'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of avoiding unnecessary lines and lengthy scripts, you can use the `columns` attribute of the dataframe. But note that, since you mentioned **vital** columns, there could be a few columns that you don't want to do the following code.:

```py
for column in m.columns:
  m[column] = m.fillna(m.groupby('P_ID')[column].transform('mean'))
```